# Setting up reactjs environemt for production

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have followed below link to set up first react Js project.

https://medium.com/@vikasharry03/react-setup-on-local-computer-912f9a551af3

Now my question is. 
Do I need to setup all this process again for my next app or there is some thing like some same environment setup and then we can use that in our apps?

Comment: You need to setup nodejs, npm and react only once. After that, you can clone any app and run without any other requirements. And please refer official doc for it - https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Comment: So that mean I need to install Babal and webpack for every app ?

Comment: @AlokMali by clone you mean copy paste and rename?

Comment: @kshitij, Yes. but if the setup not run properly then you need to update npm by the command `npm update` inside the app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You will every time you have to follow same steps because react and other helping module frequently updated by vendors, but you can paste same code files and public folder files.

and if you use this steps every time for new project, you will be aware for new changes done by vendors eg: by facebook , bable, webpack , redux etc...

Comment: So every time it will be same long process to setup an application structure like:
node_module , package.json , .balelrc , App.js , index.html

Comment: and also if I want to test reactjs offical tictack toe game then also I will have to setup all environment.?

Comment: completely environment setup i say NO, but you can paste old code present in src and public folders. because in future many JS library makers update own library frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would have but then agen you could use an application like visual studio to do the job for you.

Comment: So visual studio  do setup all this structure for us? Like I am android app developer and as we use android studio . It provides boiler plate we only need to make a new project. Set Android studio path and gradle path only for once for all.

Comment: Yes Visual studio will do the job for you, you only need to create reactjs project and bang everything is ready to use